# Define implicit conversion from one interface to another unrelated interface

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two interfaces `IFoo` and `IBar`, which both inherit from `IBase`.
How can I define the equivalent of `Narrowing`/`Widening` conversion operations so that I can implicitly or explicitly cast `IFoo` into an `IBar`?

From an implementation point of view, in my case I would have not problem in doing so because all the objects which implement `IFoo` or `IBar` have their data solely relying on a base class which implements `IBase`, that is, for example:

```
Class Product
    Implements IProduct

    Protected Property IdentityNumber as Integer

End Class    


Class TechnicalFile
    Inherits Product
    Implements ITechnicalFile

    ReadOnly Property IdentityNumber as Integer Implements ITechnicalFile.IdentityNumber
        Get
            Return MyBase.IdentityNumber 
        End Get
    End Property

End Class


Class SalesFile
    Inherits Product
    Implements ISalesFile

    Private Property DataBase as New DataBaseAPI

    Function GetBrand as String Implements ISalesFile.GetBrand 
        Dim MyProduct As IFile = DataBase.GetProductFile(Mybase.IdentityNumber)
        Return MyProduct.Brand
    End Function

End Class
```

With the above example, I would like to be able to do:

```
Dim MyTechFile as ITechnicalFile = New TechnicalFile
Dim MySalesFile as ISalesFile = MyTechFile '<- ITechnicalFile would implement an implicit conversion to ISalesFile
```

I know how to define implicit conversion for concrete classes, using `Shared Widening Operator` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-define-a-conversion-operator) for anyone interested). But since interfaces do not allow for shared members to be defined; is there another way?

Comment: If they are both `ITechnicalFile`, can you not just pass them around as the interface rather than casting between the concrete types? What's the benefit of the cast?

Comment: There's no way to do it with an implicit function, but you could do something with a member function.  The usage would potentially be a little ugly as you would have to create first then convert or else use a dummy object.

Comment: I simplified the question, but in my case I am dealing with an arborescence of generic interfaces of covariant types. Long story short, due to some architectural constraints, we end up with the need to cast from one branch to another branch of the arborescence.

Comment: @Craig, that is close to what we are doing so far: we inject a factory which implements a `Function Convert(obj as IFoo) As IBar`, but this pollutes a lot the consuming code.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by dummy object, by the way?

Comment: I mean an object created solely to be the target of a member function that returns a different object.  It's kind of a horrible hack around the absence of `Shared` interface members, where it's morally `Shared` but actually a member because that's the only way to enforce its existence through an interface (and thus be able to call it on a generic type argument).

Comment: So the `IFoo` interface would expose a function such as `Convert As MiddleObject`, and such `MiddleObject` would expose the widening operator shared members? It is an interesting case study, but hell it stinks :')